# mysql get first letter of each word

Tags: mysql

I have a column with text separated by a hyphen, for example, `hello-welcome-to-tutorials`, I want to split the text and pick the first letters of each word.

So words are `[hello, welcome, to, tutorials]`

The first letters are `hwtt`. I want to come up with a select query in MySQL for this.

This is my query:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '-', -1), 1) SEPARATOR '') from mytable
```

By I am getting only the first letter for the last word that is `t`.

How to solve this?

MySQL version is `8.0.33`

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina, version is 8.0.33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT('-', mycolumn), '-([^-])[^-]*', '$1')
FROM mytable
```

This uses a regular expression matching:

- `-` match a hyphen character (introduces a word)
- `([^-])` match any non-hyphen character, and capture (the first letter)
- `[^-]+` match zero or more non-hyphen characters (the rest of the word)

The replacement uses `$1` to refer to the captured character

Example:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT('-', 'hello-welcome-to-tutorials'), '-([^-])[^-]*', '$1') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hwtt                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you please explain the parts "'-([^-])[^-]*', '$1'"

Comment: Sure - added a bit more description

Comment: Are you trying to get the result of what Hank Hill says when asked a question?